# trying fetch the particular video in youtube through id

Tags: javascript, html, image, youtube, youtube-api

[image]

So on the above picture you can see that, I have opened Liked playlist in YouTube. And to see the 5000th liked video I have to scroll all down. But is there any way to fetch the 5000th video, in next loading or in any way.

I have tried to changing the index number as in HTML code it was "id = index", so I though it will work but it didn't.

so if there way please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=?????????

if you try right click on your page and select view page source option or as in URL browser

view-source:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=?????????

will see HTML source code and searching the id of video id inside HTML source code by find it (ctr+f)

?????????/ = id is hashing from specific private algo on YouTube code

Comment: bro there is no way this will work

Answer (score 0):

This shell command using [youtube-dl](https://youtube-dl.org/) will return you the ids of the given playlist.

```bash
youtube-dl -j --flat-playlist "PLAYLIST_ID" | jq -r '.id'
```

Example of unlisted YouTube playlist with 4,000 videos: [PL8wZFyWE1ZaI2HE7PYHvpx0_yv4oJjwAZ](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8wZFyWE1ZaI2HE7PYHvpx0_yv4oJjwAZ)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is: items (*videos*) inside a playlist are loaded *dynamically*.

You have you either scroll down in the page until you scroll at the end of it and no more videos loads or use the [answer provided by Benjamin Loison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72669688/12511801) and then, you can get the video at any given index position.

Even using the YouTube API, you have to use a *pageToken* to get the results of the *next page* / next batch of results.

I'm afraid that (*if none of the options mentioned here are valid to you*), then, there is no other way to get your desired outcome.